# Rails Session Timeout/Warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to research this all day and haven't really been able to find anything that fits my needs. We need to create a session timeout (simple) for our application, but we also need a warning message to display x minutes before the timeout of the session will occur.

I have my app set up with [the activerecord_session gem](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) and have done the necessary configuration changes. I CAN write up something like this:

```
before_action :determine_if_session_timed_out
```

in the ApplicationController. My main concern with doing it this way is db hits and the fact that it seems like there should be a rails way to do it, similar to how the above linked gem has **expire_after: xx minutes**, but for a warning.

My two questions are--has anyone seen any apps that:

- have a built-in rails way of displaying a warning when the session is about to time out?
- automatically redirect after the session times out? It looks like the page doesn't redirect with the expire_after implementation for the above gem. It stays on the same page until another action is called and then redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests in your application can be caught by this piece of code,.

```
 $(document).ajaxError(function(e, error) {   switch(error.status) {
     case 401: {
       // page redirect unauthorized access.
       location.reload();
       alert(xhr.responseText);
     }   }
```

You can have look at this approach with jquery (https://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/jquery-inactivity-warning-logout-timer-setinterval-clearinterval/)